# How to handle null string in java

Tags: java

I am .net programmer and completely new in java. I am facing problem in handling null string in java. I am assigning value from string array to string variable completeddate.
I tried all this but that didn't work.

```
String COMPLETEDATE;
COMPLETEDATE = country[23];

if(country[23] == null && country[23].length() == 0) 
{
    // ...
}

if (COMPLETEDATE.equals("null")) 
{
    // ...
}

if(COMPLETEDATE== null)
{
    // ...
}

if(COMPLETEDATE == null || COMPLETEDATE.equals("null"))
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: `country[23] == null && country[23].length() == 0` - that's a sure-fire way to get a `NullPointerException` if I've ever seen one.

Comment: [How to compare strings in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java?rq=1)

Comment: @JarrodRoberson:  It doesn't feel like this is a string comparison issue; this is an "object vs null" comparison issue.

Comment: In Java you are not allowed to call methods on a `null` object. So, if `obj==null` then `obj.anyMethod()` produces [`NPE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html).

Comment: From the looks of your last edit, you completely and drastically changed the scope of the question.  If you have another question to ask, create a new question to avoid potentially invalidating existing answers.

Answer (score 3):

For starters...the safest way to compare a `String` against a potentially `null` value is to put the guaranteed not-null `String` first, and call `.equals` on that:

```
if("constantString".equals(COMPLETEDDATE)) {
    // logic
}
```

But in general, your approach isn't correct.

The first one, as I commented, will always generate a `NullPointerException` is it's evaluated past `country[23] == null`.  If it's `null`, it doesn't have a `.length` property.  You probably meant to call `country[23] != null` instead.

The second approach only compares it against the literal string `"null"`, which may or may not be true given the scope of your program.  Also, if `COMPLETEDDATE` itself is null, it will fail - in that case, you would rectify it as I described above.

Your third approach is correct in the sense that it's the only thing checking against `null`.  Typically though, you would want to do some logic if the object you wanted *wasn't* `null`.

Your fourth approach is correct by accident; if `COMPLETEDDATE` is actually `null`, the `OR` will short-circuit.  It could also be true if `COMPLETEDDATE` was equal to the literal `"null"`.

Answer (score 1):

To check null string you can use **Optional** in Java 8 as below:
import Optional

```
import java.util.Optional;
```

import it as above

```
String str= null;
Optional<String> str2 = Optional.ofNullable(str);
```

then use **isPresent()** , it will return false if str2 contains NULL otherwise true

```
if(str2.isPresent())
{
//If No NULL 
}
else
{
//If NULL
}
```

reference: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear what you are asking, but to check if a String variable is null, use the following statement.

```
if(myString==null)
```

This checks whether the object reference is null.

The following statement, which you have written is incorrect for two reasons.

```
if (COMPLETEDATE.equals("null")) 
                    {
                        // ...

                    }
```

**1.** `null` is a keyword in Java, `"null"` is just a string of text.

**2.** `.equals()` checks to see if two objects are equal according to the given method's definition of equality. Null checks should always be made using the == comparison operator, as it checks reference equality.

Comment: thanks Jake.I have edited my question for more clearification

Answer (score 0):

If a variable is null, you cannot dereference it.

That means you can not invoke methods on it.

So... The following if statement will throw a NullPointerException every time the first clause is true:

`if (a == null && a.length() == 0)`

In other words: if `a` is null, you *CANNOT* invoke the length method on `a`.