# How to handle null values in Java (eclipse IDE)

Tags: java, eclipse, nullpointerexception, lombok

I'm working on an API (Eclipse IDE - Kepler), JDK 1.7)
I need a shortcut like 
*@IfNotNullUpdate*

consider the following e.g.

```
Model model = new Model();
String field1 = entity.getField1() != null ? entity.getField1() : "";
model.setField1(field1);
```

so that I can simply write it like

```
model.setField1( @IfNotNullUpdate entity.getField1(),"");
```

I don't want to have any NullPointerExceptions. It will be a great help If it can work like builder pattern. for e.g.

```
model.addField_25(@IfNotNullUpdate entity.getField_37())
     .addField_16(@IfNotNullUpdate entity.getField_69());
```

I tried @NonNull of [lombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/NonNull.html). It just ensures that param is not null which is not my requirement.

And of-course assert() can't be a solution. Hope I'm able to explain my requirement well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle null string in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22902705/how-to-handle-null-string-in-java)

Comment: It is not a duplicate. He likes to know if there is an existing solution for auto setting the values.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271526/avoiding-null-statements-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html). Using the sample provided, the following can throw a NPE if any of the methods called returns a null value:

```
String version = computer.getSoundcard().getUSB().getVersion();
```

To avoid that or excessive `if (x != null)` checks, using `Optional` you can use:

```
String name = computer.flatMap(Computer::getSoundcard)
                          .flatMap(Soundcard::getUSB)
                          .map(USB::getVersion)
                          .orElse("UNKNOWN");
```

Comment: I think those checks seem less complicated and more readable than this though.

Comment: @Zar Not when you have 10+ nested `if` null-checks.

Comment: @M.Shaw I do agree this is the best bet. I have some more time to bring in JDK 8 (Backward compatibility). I'm eager to use this. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: @DVSanthoshKiran If it solved your problem please mark it as the answer.

Comment: @M.Shaw I'm yet exploring options with Java 7

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use just a method? You can make it static if you want, so that you can access it by className. Or put your helper methods that you need in oneClass and extend it.

```
public String getFieldValue(Object o ){
    if(o instanceof someEntity){
        someEntity se = (someEntity) o
        if(someEntity.getField() != null){
            return someEntity.getField();
        }else{
            return ""; 
        }
    }else if(o instanceof someOtherEntity){
       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this practically viable if i have some thousands of entities and models each with hundreds of fields?

Comment: guess not if you have many of them. Then you can use reflection:

Comment: `Public String getField(Object bean, String methodName){
        BeanInfo info = Introspector.getBeanInfo(bean.getClass(), Object.class);
     PropertyDescriptor[] props = info.getPropertyDescriptors();
  String value;
     for (PropertyDescriptor pd : props) {
         Method getter = pd.getReadMethod();
   if(getter.getName().equals(methodName)){
          //add try catch
                //get the value from method
          value = getter.invoke(bean);
    if(value != null)return value;
   }
         
        }
        return "";
}`

Answer (score 0):

You would need to build a custom annotation for this or any purpose of yours. You can create an Annotation for you with `@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)` and sue reflection to map it as required. But this is so lengthy process which doesn't need much of your time. Instead just write a method and just call it.

I can't think of an API readily available. As you pointed out, lombok doesn't do that for you.

Comment: Yeah, Custom annotation doesn't worth the time. I'm actually looking for an existing solution.

Answer (score 0):

Updating answer with JDK17:

I have a helper method like

```
public class NpeHelper {
 public static <T> Optional<T> ofNullable(final Supplier<T> resolver) {
        try {
            final T result = resolver.get();
            return Optional.ofNullable(result);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    }
}
```

I can use this helper function as

```
model.addField_25(NpeHelper.ofNullable(()-> entity.getField_37()).orElse(<AnyObject<));
```

For Nullable streams validation I'm using
ApacheCommons' [CollectionUtils.emptyIfNull()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html#emptyIfNull-java.util.Collection-);